# Facebook Profile name with Fancy and Stylish Font

Tags: facebook, font

I have found some people are writing their profile name in fancy and stylish font. How do I write a name or add some stylish font to the profile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Facebook does not officially support changing the font on your profile. Some people manage to make it look like this by putting in script characters (Hindi, etc.) that look vaguely similar to English letters, or by combining Unicode characters.

But this does have some downsides:

1. A lot of people find it annoying.
2. People searching for your name won't see it, because your name in Facebook's database won't actually be the characters of your name that people would be searching for.

I would suggest that you not do this, but if you really want to, you'll have to look for special characters that look like letters.

Comment: but if i want to add special symbol and thereby write a name in fancy way then what i have to do ??

Comment: I don't know of any easy way to do it... you just have to open up the character map and look for characters that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook specify in their terms and conditions that you cant use symbols or punctuation or characters from multiple languages in your facebook name: https://www.facebook.com/help/112146705538576

However it is possible to change the font style via unicode mapping tools.

See http://www.panix.com/~eli/unicode/convert.cgi?text=my+fancy+name

For some examples of what you can do, you just need to type in the text you want to convert, then copy and paste the results.

I have seen some people with names using multiple unicode characters from different languages, but if Facebook catch you they may get you to change it to a normal type name.