# How can I make my Facebook profile name into stylish name?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Profile name with Fancy and Stylish Font](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/facebook-profile-name-with-fancy-and-stylish-font)

How can I change my Facebook profile name with stylish color?